# How to debug a Vigenere cipher in C?

Tags: c, vigenere

I am trying to make a Vigenere cipher. My problem is that I'm not getting the expected output. When running the program it gives this output: HFNLP WPTLE. The correct output should be: HFNLP YOSND.

I think that the problem resides in the bad use of modulo (mod). When I try to wrap around the key (ABC) with the variable `i`, the space (" ") in the plainText also wraps, affecting directly the result of the wrapping. I don't what to do in order to get the right output.

```
string plainText = "HELLO WORLD";   
string keyword =   "ABC";

 for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plainText);i++)
 {  

    int wrap =  (int) strlen( keyword) % (int) strlen(plainText);

     if(isalpha(plainText[i]))
     {

     int upper = 'A' + (plainText[i] + (toupper(keyword[i % wrap]))) % 26;
     printf("%c", upper);

     }
```

Comment: Hint: you need an additional piece of data to do this. An iteration must know in some way how many spaces have been encountered up to this point. There are several ways to track that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index of keys on non-alphabetic characters must not increase.

An example of  fix:

```
char *keyp = keyword;
char ch;
for(int i = 0; ch = plainText[i]; i++){  
    if(isalpha(ch)){
        putchar('A' + (toupper(ch) - 'A' + toupper(*keyp++) - 'A') % 26);
        if(!*keyp)
            keyp = keyword;
    } else
        putchar(ch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me. :)